# Column order in twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

my first question here so I apologize if I'm doing this wrong.

So I've got this piece of code:

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-8">
  col-md-8
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
  col-md-4
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-8">
  col-md-8
 </div>    
</div>
```

which shows:

```
[8] [4]
[8]
```

My question is, how do I manipulate the column order to be like this:

```
[8] first
[8] second
[4]
```

when view-port < sm. With the code I have right now it currently shows:

```
[8] first
[4] 
[8] second
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think "mobile first" and use nesting like this..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">8</div>
            <div class="col-md-12">8</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        4
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/tQEH7GQ0ns

Read more about [Bootstrap column ordering](http://blog.codeply.com/2015/04/06/responsive-bootstrap-layouts/)

Answer (score 0):

The reordering you would like to do is a tad bit tricky but bootstrap has developed a method to reorder columns depending on the view using **push** and **pull** classes. These sources should do trick and help you figure out the solution for your implementation.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap

https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/pushpull-columns-for-only-smaller-screen-sizes-in-bootstrap-3/

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanx skelly ! yes i didnt realise that it could be done using the row i thought the row would not override in desktop view as explained in your code. Thanks for the info !